# SQL select из четырех таблиц

Tags: mysql

Не знаю какую конструкцию mysql использовать. У меня есть четыре таблицы:

таблица книг авторов: 
author_id book_id

таблица, содержащая название и описание книги: 
book_id title description

таблица содержащая главы книг:
chapter_id book_id

таблица, содержащая наименования глав:
chapter_id chapter_title

Как я могу получить всю информацию по каждой книге и её главам, имея id автора в MySQL? 
Использование простого селекта результата не дало, workbench даже запрос не переваривает.

Comment: Ключи у таблиц есть??

Comment: А в каком виде выбрать ? В результате одного запроса может быть только плоская таблица. А тут как бы информация трехмерная. Думаю наиболее правильным было бы вытягивать ее по отдельности и выкладывать  нужную структуру уже на клиенте

Comment: @DmitryD foreign keys имеются в виду? да, есть.

Comment: @Mike ну в итоге должна получится подобная структура в xml <BooksList>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <Title>AAAA</Title>
        <Description>BBBB</Description>
        <Chapters>
            <row>
                <id>1</id>
                <Title>Chapter 1</Title>
            </row>
        </Chapters>
    </row>
</BooksList>
Я не знаю насколько это возможно, поскольку не приходилось такое делать до этого, поэтому в целом будет достаточно указать направление, в котором пробовать

Comment: Значит вытягивать все отдельными запросами и раскладывать уже на клиенте в нужную структуру. Максимум что можно собрать одним запросом это названия глав с главами (если конечно там связь один к одному. Не понимаю почему они в отдельных таблицах)